# Selenium tests are throwing error after successful test execution

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-chromedriver

After the tests are executed I get an error which is mostly coming from the second execution time. I have tried the latest selenium version (3.13) with  latest chrome driver (2.40) also.

Note: Tests were passing till yesterday and I am notice this issue from today.

**Following is the code for closing the driver.**

```
WebDriver driver = WebDriverFactory.getDriver();
   if (driver != null) {
      System.out.println("Base Class's AfterClass started to quit the driver....");
      driver.quit();
   }
```

**Exception I am getting is as follows:**

```
Jul 17, 2018 8:48:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
INFO: Unable to drain process streams. Ignoring but the exception being swallowed follows.
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: The stop timeout of 2000 ms was exceeded (Exit value: -559038737)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stopThread(PumpStreamHandler.java:295)
    at org.apache.commons.exec.PumpStreamHandler.stop(PumpStreamHandler.java:181)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess.destroy(OsProcess.java:135)
    at org.openqa.selenium.os.CommandLine.destroy(CommandLine.java:153)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.stop(DriverService.java:222)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:95)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:543)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:600)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.quit(RemoteWebDriver.java:443)
    at commontestbase.ClientTestBase.tearDownAfterMethod(ClientTestBase.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethodConsideringTimeout(MethodInvocationHelper.java:59)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:455)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:222)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:643)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:71)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.call(TestMethodWithDataProviderMethodWorker.java:14)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Jul 17, 2018 8:48:33 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.OsProcess destroy
SEVERE: Unable to kill process java.lang.ProcessImpl@1970552
Base AfterMethod started....
Base AfterMethod started to quit the driver....


----------


Default Suite
Total tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0


----------
```

Comment: Share some additional information, have your tried the same with Firefox browser?

Comment: is the above code in after class or after method? are you trying to quit in two places?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that your driver process is not getting killed .
You can try killing them (chromedriver.exe or geckodriver.exe or IEDriverServer.exe) by using taskkill commands or by manually killing the processes using TaskManager.

For eg.

```
taskkill /f /im chromedriver-2.35.exe /im geckodriver-v0.19.1.exe /im IEDriverServer.exe
```

May be that helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see the issue comes only when the process, chromedriver.exe is not getting killed. Do you have any idea, why suddenly its not getting killed? Note, this works fine for 2 to 3 times once I restart my computer. I was not able to kill the process using taskkill or taskmanager.

Comment: Try to execute this command using ProcessBuilder in java after finishing of execution. It should kill the process manually also , but in your case I am not getting why it is not working.

Comment: or you can use like : Runtime.getRuntime().exec("taskkill /IM " + process_name + " /F");

Comment: Thanks! I will try and let you know how it goes.